# Distance between 2 locations

Tags: java, geocoding, geo

I need to be able to work out the distance between 2 houses in my local area, unfortunately I can't find anything that seems to work. The I've looked at Google Maps Java Engine, however that will be disabled at the start of next year, so is out of the question.

I need to be able to take an input of:

```
"1 Blue Road"
```

and work out the distance to, by road and path to, in meters (or smallest measurements possible", to

```
"2 Red Road"
```

A preference is that it works offline, using a file of the local area as I am expecting to do lots of queries to it, so preferably don't want query limits. This is because I am doing this for a school project, so I need to be able to create a network of all the houses and the distances between them, as I need to be able to apply a shortest path algorithm to it, by myself, to prove that the program is complex. I'm not bothered about efficiency of this program.

I also need a little help on setting up the "system" because I've seen files before that help you find the distance between 2 locations, but the problem is that I've not been able to find a tutorial of how to set up and use.

Comment: Did you try anything? Maybe even drawing basic UML diagram for your problem?

Comment: Not yet, not been able to figure out how to use anything that I've found so far.